# Hide Bootstrap side navbar when click outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this `left side bar` and all i want is that `side nav` to close when clicked outside of it.

My `side nav` javascript code

```
//side-nav is the class of my side nav 
//leftmenutrigger is my button on nav bar the toggles the side nav
```

Any suggestions will do. Even javascript or css just to hide my side nav bar.

My navigation bar and left side nav bar codes

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.leftmenutrigger').on('click', function(e) {
     $('.side-nav').toggleClass("open"); 
     e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar header-top sticky-top navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light bg-light" >
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon leftmenutrigger"></span>          <!--THIS IS THE BUTTON THAT TOGGLES-->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="images/nexuslogo.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" id="comp_name" name="comp_name"> Nexus Technologies, Inc.</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText"
         aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span> </button>        
         
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText" name="navbarText" > //SIDE NAV BAR ITEMS
    <ul class="navbar-nav animate side-nav ">         
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a  href="" id="addUser" name="addUser" style="width: 100%"> 
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add User                   
        </a>               
          <a href="manageprize.php" id="manage_prize" name="manage_prize" style="width: 100%" target="_self"> 
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i> Manage Prizes                 
         </a>                                
    </li>         
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

THANKS!!!!

Comment: Judging by the class names, I think you're using bootstrap on your site. If that is the case, then you can just use the in-built nav functionalities provided by Bootstrap itself for toggling your nav.

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: @AndrewL can you send me some link of boostrap documentation on navs? Thanks btw!

Comment: Nav documentation for [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Comment: @לבנימלכה the latest version of bootstrap!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example from **Bootstrap 3**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

And the **JS code** that works for me:

1. Anywhere outside **.navbar-collapse** :

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    var navbarCollapse = $(".navbar-collapse");               
    var navbarCollapseOpened = navbarCollapse.hasClass("in");
    if (navbarCollapseOpened && !target.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {      
        navbarCollapse.collapse("hide");
    }
});
```

2. Anywhere outside **.navbar**:

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
    var navigation = $(event.target).parents(".navbar").length;
    if(!navigation) {
        $(".navbar .navbar-collapse").collapse("hide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `onclick` `window` and remove class `show` if exist..

Also use `onclick` the nav to prevent collapse

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {

   if($(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("show")){
      $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass("show"); 
      e.preventDefault();
      }
});
 $('.navbar-collapse').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar header-top sticky-top navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light bg-light" >
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon leftmenutrigger"></span>          <!--THIS IS THE BUTTON THAT TOGGLES-->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="images/nexuslogo.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" id="comp_name" name="comp_name"> Nexus Technologies, Inc.</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText"
         aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span> </button>        
         
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText" name="navbarText" > //SIDE NAV BAR ITEMS
    <ul class="navbar-nav animate side-nav ">         
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a  href="" id="addUser" name="addUser" style="width: 100%"> 
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add User                   
        </a>               
          <a href="manageprize.php" id="manage_prize" name="manage_prize" style="width: 100%" target="_self"> 
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i> Manage Prizes                 
         </a>                                
    </li>         
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // If user clicks inside the element
    if (event.target.closest(".side-nav")){
       $('.side-nav').removeClass("open"); 
    };
});
```

It will handle clicking outside element in jQuery.

It use event bubbling. When user click in any element inside .side-nav event is going upper to the document and if somewhere we .side-nav as a ancestor of such element it means that click was made inside.